# Equivalent of adding a value in a new row/column to numpy that works like R's data.frame

Tags: python, arrays, r, numpy

In R I can do:

```
> y = c(2,3)
> x = c(4,5)
> z = data.frame(x,y)
> z[3,3]<-6
> z
   x  y V3
1  4  2 NA
2  5  3 NA
3 NA NA  6
```

R automatically fills the empty cells with NA.
If I use [numpy.insert](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.insert.html) from [numpy](http://www.numpy.org/), numpy throws by default an error:

```
import numpy

y = [2,3]
x = [4,5]
z = numpy.array([y, x])

z = numpy.insert(z, 3, 6, 3)

IndexError: axis 3 is out of bounds for an array of dimension 2
```

Is there a way to insert values in a way that works similar to R in numpy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[numpy](http://www.numpy.org/) is more of a replacement for R's matrices, and not so much for its data frames. You should consider using python's [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/) library for this. For example:

```
In [1]: import pandas

In [2]: y = pandas.Series([2,3])

In [3]: x = pandas.Series([4,5])

In [4]: z = pandas.DataFrame([x,y])

In [5]: z
Out[5]: 
   0  1
0  4  5
1  2  3

In [19]: z.loc[3,3] = 6

In [20]: z
Out[20]: 
    0   1   3
0   4   5 NaN
1   2   3 NaN
3 NaN NaN   6
```

Answer (score 1):

In numpy you need to initialize an array with the appropriate size:

```
z = numpy.empty(3, 3)
z.fill(numpy.nan)
z[:2, 0] = x
z[:2, 1] = z
z[3,3] = 6
```

Comment: What do I do if I already have an array and later want to add something beyond the size with was used to initialize the array?

Comment: you can use the numpy.resize function. But the undefined elements will not be "NaN" in that case, so you have to be careful about the content after resizing.
Also you can use the functions numpy.append, numpy.hstack and numpy.vstack which all increase the size in one dimension.

In General, it is better to keep the shape fixed, because thats the "normal" usage of arrays and the array operations are quite fast. Changing the shape is slow.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a more R-like experience within python, I can highly recommend [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/), which is a higher-level numpy based library, which performs operations of this kind.

Comment: If you want a more R-like experience, I recommend using R. :-)

Comment: Aside from being at odds with the explicitly stated aims of the OP, I would add that R is a pretty terrible MATLAB-tier hack, as far as aspiring to be a general-purpose programming language is concerned. 'Wanting a more R-like experience' as far as library functionality is concerned and 'wanting R' are two rather different things.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the raised error is possible to understand why it occurred:
you are trying to insert values in an axes non existent in `z`.

you can fix it doing

```
import numpy as np
y = [2,3]
x = [4,5]
array = np.array([y, x])
z = np.insert(array, 1, [3,6], axis=1))
```

The interface is quite different from the R's one. If you are using [IPython](http://ipython.org/),
you can easily access the documentation for some numpy function, in this case
`np.insert`, doing:

```
help(np.insert)
```

which gives you the function signature, explain each parameter used to call it and provide
some examples.

you could, alternatively do

```
import numpy as np
x = [4,5]
y = [2,3]
array = np.array([y,x])
z = [3,6]
new_array = np.vstack([array.T, z]).T  # or, as below
# new_array = np.hstack([array, z[:, np.newaxis])
```

Also, give a look at the [Pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/) module. It provides 
an interface similar to what you asked, implemented with numpy.

With `pandas` you could do something like:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'y':[2,3], 'x':[4,5]}
dataframe = pd.DataFrame(data)
dataframe['z'] = [3,6]
```

which gives the nice output:

```
    x   y   z
0   4   2   3
1   5   3   5
```